# Can't display database records

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo sql database records in my page and I am using this code. When I run it doesn't display the result from the db. I have records in the database that match the criteria. I am new in php and sql so please tell where I have mistakes.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header('Location:vhod.php');
    exit;
}

$pageTitle = 'СЪОБЩЕНИЯ';
include 'includes/header.html'; 

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

include 'php/db_connect.php';

$msgs = '';
$query = 'SELECT `timestamp`, `to`, `sender`, `subject`, `msg` FROM msg WHERE `to`="$name"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $msgs = "ДАТА: " . $row["timestamp"] . " >> От: " . $row["sender"] . " >> Тема: " . $row["subj"] . " >> Съобщение: " . $row["msg"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    $msgs = "Нямате съобщения :(";
}
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: btw, you selected the `subject` column in the query, but using `subj` in `$row["subj"]` and MySQL would have thrown you something about it, as in "non-existant column".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try modifying the lower part of your code like this.

```
  $msgs = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE to=$name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $msgs = "ДАТА: " . $row['timestamp'] . " >> От: " . $row['sender'] . " >> Тема: " . $row['subj'] . " >> Съобщение: " . $row['msg'] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        $msgs = "Нямате съобщения :(";
    }
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: are you sure msg table exists? Or mysql connection works properly?, What was your earlier error?

Comment: my msg table exists. I found out that it always shows the message in the else {} statement (talking about this: "Нямате съобщения :(")